# Using Azure KeyVault for React Native

Tags: android, ios, azure, react-native, azure-keyvault

I am not using Azure Active Directory authentication in my React Native application.

I want to keep some keys on the cloud so that a user can easily configure without redeploying the complete application.

I was thinking about Azure KeyVault, so the question is, is it possible to use key vault, can I do without showing the authentication page.

If there is any other solution for this let me know.

Comment: what sor of keys? can you add more details

Comment: Any kind of string data, the user can dynamically change. One option is firebase, I want to be sure that if we can do this with Azure key vault without login redirect

Comment: Did you found a solution to use azure key vault in react native environment?

Answer (score 1):

You can use script code to get the value of the key. Don't need to showing the authentication page.

Below is a simple console code:

```
//const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { ClientSecretCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { SecretClient } = require("@azure/keyvault-secrets");

const readline = require('readline');

function askQuestion(query) {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });

    return new Promise(resolve => rl.question(query, ans => {
        rl.close();
        resolve(ans);
    }))
}

async function main() {

  const keyVaultName = "bowmantest";
  const KVUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";

  //const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
  tenantId = "e4c9ab4e-bdxxxxxx-230ba2a757fb";
  clientId = "d340361e-5dxxxxxxbaf4-6e81aed46ed9";
  clientSecret = "2X~43qA-~J2xxxxxxnT1a7_O2-dKyTK";
  const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
  const client = new SecretClient(KVUri, credential);

  const secretName = "testbowmansecret";

  console.log("Retrieving your secret from " + keyVaultName + ".");

  const retrievedSecret = await client.getSecret(secretName);

  console.log("Your secret is '" + retrievedSecret.value + "'.");

}

main()
```

And I can get: (don't need to go to authentication page, but authentication is still needed.)

[image]

By the way, you need to give the AD app the access permission:

[image]

This is the api documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/identity/clientsecretcredential?view=azure-node-latest

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40azure/keyvault-secrets/secretclient?view=azure-node-latest

(You can find everything about JavaScript with Azure in above documentation).

Comment: It's just running fine only for node environment but not working in react native environment. Did anyone find a solution to use azure key vault in react native environment?

Comment: This library meant for NodeJS, I don't think that is a secured to use it in the client side